# Is there a tutorial on how to use AREL or Reference document?

Tags: arel

I am looking :

- for a reference document that lists what methods are available?
- a tutorial on how to setup and execute a query, then build up complex queries?

Checked README, questions that are tagged as Arel here but most are about how to setup where clauses, complex queries not how to use it in the first place ...

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 4):

[Generated docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/frames/Arel) are your best bet if you're looking for an official reference.

As for tutorial, [these cool slides](http://www.slideshare.net/flah00/activerecord-arel) helped me learn arel (props to [Philip C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456636/philip-c)).